# Python script keeps running when using pyRserve

Tags: python, r, pyrserve

I am trying to learn how to send a list of lists in Python to R -script which runs statistical methods and gives two or three data frames back to Python

I stumbled across the pyRserve package. I was able to follow the manual in their documentation and everything works great in command line  (>>> ). When I run a script, it does not stop.  I have installed Rserve package and started its service in RStudio. Below is the code:

```
import pyRserve
print "here1" #prints this line...
conn = pyRserve.connect(host='localhost', port=6311)
print "here2"
a= conn.eval('3+5')
print a
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Why are you calling connect twice?

Comment: Sorry, that would be a typo. keeping either line of .connect() would still keep the python script running.

Answer (score 1):

The ([docs](https://pythonhosted.org/pyRserve/manual.html#setting-up-a-connection-to-rserve)) suggest:

```
$ python
>>> import pyRserve
>>> conn = pyRserve.connect()
```

And then go on with:

> To connect to a different location host and port can be specified explicitly:

```
pyRserve.connect(host='localhost', port=6311)
```

This is not meant to indicate that both lines should be run.  The second line should be viewed as a potential modifier for the first.  So *if* you need an alternate address or port, then it should look like:

```
$ python
>>> import pyRserve
>>> conn = pyRserve.connect(host='localhost', port=6311)
```

Also note this caveat for windows users:

> Note On some windows versions it might be necessary to always provide ‘localhost’ for connecting to a locally running Rserve instance.